# Azure Kubernetes Ingress do not route to subdomain

Tags: azure, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

Had working azure kubernetes service (AKS) with mydomain.com.
Moved webapp to another host.

- Added DNS A entries:
- mydomain.com -> new server IP;
- old.mydomain.com -> old azure public IP;

I need to keep old.mydomain.com routing to old AKS webapp, but insted ingress always redirect to new server - mydomain.com.

How to make rule to still access existing azure kubernetes web app?

Used yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: old-web
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - old.mydomain.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: old.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: / 
        backend:
          serviceName: webapp
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: The ingress will route the traffic inside the cluster to a service.
A service could be internal or external, but I don't think it's the problem here, it's more like a DNS cache issue with your http client.

If you are on linux/mac, try to edit `/etc/hosts` with your new ip and old.mydomain.com domain and test again.

Comment: @jmaitrehenry It's definitely not a DNS problem. I can ping my both domains with correct IP response. More of that the web request are hitting ingress service successfully. Fiddler shows 302 response from server that means that some kind of redirections going on behind th scene.Could it be related with nginx server itself? Virtual host settings? I'm not big guru of that kubernetes world, so i'm trying to start troubleshoot from some point.

Comment: did you check nginx-ingress logs? maybe your certificate doesn't support sub-domains